# Best Practice to Subclass System Class' in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, subclass, edit, subclassing

I'm working on a Win32 wrapper class. I have initially been subclassing EditBox's the following way:

```
// Create the Edit Box
Edit_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(.., "Edit", ...);

Edit_OldProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(Edit_hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC);
SetWindowLongPtr(Edit_hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)EditWndProc);

// Then in EditWndProc(...):

return CallWindowProc(Edit_OldProc, hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
```

I've just come across a new method which set's the Window Procedure with System Class'. Would this be a more preferred method?? I'm really surprised I've never seen this as I've been over hundreds of subclassing sources.

New Method:

```
WNDCLASS wc;

GetClassInfoEx(hInstance, "Edit", &wc);
wc.lpszClassName = L"NewEditClass";
Edit_OldProc     = wc.lpfnWndProc;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = EditWndProc
RegisterClassEx(&wc);

// Create the Edit Box
CreateWindowEx(.., "NewEditClass", ...);

// Then in EditWndProc(...):

return Edit_OldProc(hWnd, Message, lParam, wParam);
```

Comment: The second method is "super-classing", not "sub-classing".

Comment: After looking up super-classing that explains the differences clearly. Thanks!

Comment: Best practices for subclassing controls can be found at [Subclassing Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx). It details the problems associated with your (first) code snippet and how to solve it ([`SetWindowSubclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx)).